# How to search a specific item in a string collection in java1.8 using Lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection of items as under

```
List<String> lstRollNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
lstRollNumber.add("1");
lstRollNumber.add("2");
lstRollNumber.add("3");
lstRollNumber.add("4");
```

Now I want to search a particular `RollNumber` in that collection. Say

```
String rollNumberToSearch = "3";
```

I can easily do it by looping through the collection and checking for every items and if there is any match, i can break through the loop and return a true from the function.

But I want to use the **Lambda expression** for doing this.

In C# we use(among other options),

```
var flag = lstRollNumber.Exists(x => x == rollNumberToSearch);
```

How to do the same in Java 1.8 ?

I tried with

```
String rollNumberToSearch = "3";
Stream<String> filterRecs = lstRollNumbers.stream().filter(rn -> rn.equals(rollNumberToSearch));
```

But I know it is wrong? 
Please guide.

Comment: You can use the Predicate interface. Just check the "Collections" part here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are using stream *intermediate* operation `filter` without calling the stream *terminal* operation. Read about the types of stream operations in [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). If you still want to use `filter` (for learning purposes) you can solve your task with `findAny()` or `anyMatch()`:

```
boolean flag = lstRollNumbers.stream().filter(rn -> rn.equals(rollNumberToSearch))
                             .findAny().isPresent();
```

Or

```
boolean flag = lstRollNumbers.stream().filter(rn -> rn.equals(rollNumberToSearch))
                             .anyMatch(rn -> true);
```

Or don't use `filter` at all (as @marstran suggests):

```
boolean flag = lstRollNumbers.stream().anyMatch(rn -> rn.equals(rollNumberToSearch));
```

Also note that method reference can be used here:

```
boolean flag = lstRollNumbers.stream().anyMatch(rollNumberToSearch::equals);
```

However if you want to use this not for learning, but in production code, it's much easier and faster to use good old [`Collection.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
boolean flag = lstRollNumber.contains("3");
```

The contains method can be optimized according to the collection type. For example, in `HashSet` it would be just hash lookup which is way faster than `.stream().anyMatch(...)` solution. Even for `ArrayList` calling `contains` would be faster.

Answer (score 6):

Use `anyMatch`. It returns `true` if any element in the stream matches the predicate:

```
String rollNumberToSearch = "3";
boolean flag = lstRollNumbers.stream().anyMatch(rn -> rn.equals(rollNumberToSearch));
```

Comment: And of course, as Tagir Valeev mentions, `lstRollnumbers.contains(rollNumberToSearch)` is better in this particular case.